# topology of metric spaces and isolated points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've a doubt about an inclusion which I have to prove according to an exercise. Actually, let (E,d) a metric space, and bd(P) the boundary of a subset P, and P(is) the isolated points of P. I have to show : P(is) included in P ∩ bd(P).

But let E={1} and d(x,y) = |x-y|. Then, (E,d) is a metric space (d is a metric), 1 is an isolated point of E cause B(1,r) = {x€E | |x-1| < r} = {1} for all r>0, so for example B(1,r) ∩ E = {1} != ∅, but 1 is not in bd(E), because B(1,r) ∩ E\E = ∅.

So, if i've didn't make a mistake somewhere, the inclusion is wrong. Is it true, or i've commit a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: I don't see any errors - what is the exact statement of the problem?

Comment: The exact statement is : Show that P(is) is included in bd(P) ∩ P.
Thank you for helping me. :)

Comment: Well, there may be some detail I'm missing, so I won't say this as an answer, but I think you are right, especially if the question was written by your instructor. If that's the wording in a textbook, then it's more likely that the textbook is defining one of the terms in a nonstandard way.

Comment: I think this is only true if the set $E$ isn't composed entirely of isolated points. In this case all the isolated points are part of the interior.

Comment: Okay, I think it's a question which was written by my instructor, and it's probably a wrong statement. I also think that it's true if E has not itself an isolated point. Because if it's the case, and if we consider E(is) and x an isolated point of E, then x is in E(is) but not in bd(E).

Thank you for the help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the assumption that $E$ itself has no isolated points. In that case the isolated points of a subset $P$ are in the intersection $P \cap \partial P$. If $E$ has an isolated point $p$ (Like your example) the statement is never true because then $P = \{p\}$ is clopen (so has empty boundary), while $P^{\text{is}}$ is just $P$ itself.

Comment: It solve my problem, thank you ! :)